# Custom UITableViewCell label text doesn't change back on deselect

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uiappearance

I have a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. I am customizing the labels contained within the cell by setting some attributes of `UILabel`'s appearance proxy, as follows:

```
[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil].textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil].highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

When I select the cell in the UI, the labels' colors change as expected and the code performs a push segue to the next view controller. However, when I pop this new view controller and go back to the screen with the custom `UITableViewCell`s, the highlighted text color remains even though I am deselecting the cell in the code as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]) {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    }
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Is this a bug in iOS 7 or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I won't call it a bug but there is a way to fix it.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

  [super viewWillDisappear:YES];

  if ([self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]) {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]    animated:YES];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jamie, I faced the exact same situation. I have a `UIView` as `contentView` of `UITableViewCell` and the `UITableView` is in a `UIPopoverController`. The selection highlight wouldn't clear if I reopen the popover after dismissing it.

I did try both the solutions mentioned here and as you say both do not work. While debugging I realized `UITableView` somehow loses the selection and returns nothing for `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Unfortunately I did not find a very good solution. I would call this an iOS 7 bug as 
UITableView does not behave as before and as expected.

The solution that I employed was to change background color of my `UIView` instead of using `UITableView`'s selection methods and change it back to default color in `viewWillDisappear`.

I am all eyes to read a better solution.